# asp.net add control to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, controls

is it possible to add a user control in a datatable in asp.net c#? The following code produces this: System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox instead of an input

```
    dr[0] = new TextBox (); // where dr is a dataRow and the datatable is 
                            // bound to a datagrid in the user control
```

Comment: It may be better that you tell us what you are trying to achieve because a DataTable is used for transferring data to and from a database and I don't see what a TextBox in a database is going to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know, datatable can keep any data (may be in string format in your case) and give the output. But That doesnt mean that it will show you the control instead of textbox in output.
To display Textbox in output there are other methods.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider this as the answer. I was trying to create a dynamic table which the columns, rows and the content will be determined by the end-user. As a solution, I came with up with constructing a datatable and then binding the actual table and constructing it according to the data within the datatable

Comment: @Shaokan: DataTable has nothing to do with controls. It only holds data.